# Debugging WebService solution in VS at localhost

Tags: asp.net, web-services, debugging

I have a WebService solution with Sample.svc and Sample.svc.cs containing a method like;

```
public override ResponseClass GenerateResponse(RequestClass request)
{
     // Some code here.
}
```

I want to test and debug code  line by line with adding breakpoints, but i do not have any knowledge about how to do it?

How can i debug the webservice code?

Comment: How will you call it ? From another application or directly from browser ?

Comment: I will call from another application

Comment: OK than host the service in IIS.Than you need to attach process from which service is running when a method will be called breakpoint will hit at that.

Comment: can i do that with using tools like soapUI or WCFStorm. I mean call webservice method with these tools and debug code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do following there may be other ways.

1. Host the service in IIS.
2. Now open code of service from VS.
3. Go to Debug
4. Click on Attach to process.
5. Select the process in which service is running.
6. Put breakpoint at method which you want to debug.
7. Now call that method from other application it will hit break point.

Comment: is there a tutorial for hosting the service in IIS ?

Comment: Simply go to IIS and add website it is very easy.

Comment: Mairaj: i am using soap ui, wcfstorm and wcf test client tools to test a method (GenerateResponse in question text) , but it is not listed there.